# adding menu bar in SherlockFragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-intent

i want to add the menu in my class getting Error **Cannot override the final method from SherlockFragment ** please tell me how to do this

my code is

```
public class FragementFirst extends SherlockFragment{

    Button btn;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragementone, container, false);
                btn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.butto);
                setHasOptionsMenu(true);
                btn.setOnClickListener(new  OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FirstActiviry.class);
              getActivity().startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.first, menu);
    }
}

    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:id="@+id/action_task"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_xhdpi"
      android:title="hello"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

please use

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.first, menu);
    }
```

instead of

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.first, menu);
    }
```

to understand a tutorial is there
please visit http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-action-items-from-within-fragments/